# Add content in different text style to uiwebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uifont

I am making an iPhone app which provides the user to get text in different text style. For it, I have used uiwebview instead of textview or label so that user will be able to add images like smileys. For converting the normal text in a text style i.e. gatsbycaps we are using gatsbycaps.ttf file and trying to convert the text in this format I have used following code

```
  NSString* htmlContentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"<style type=\"text/css\"> @font-face { font-family: 
                               gatsbycaps;}</style><p style=\"font-family:gatsbycaps;
                                \">sudha</p>"];
NSLog(@"htmlContentString..:%@",htmlContentString);

[styleTextWebView loadHTMLString:htmlContentString baseURL:nil];
```

But there is no output by using above code. Please tell us that how to implement text style in webview by using ttf file. Any help from your side will be really appreciated.

Thanks to all.

Comment: In any case you will need to include the custom font in your app. It may be easier to just add the custom font and use a standard textview setting the font to your custom one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CoreText` for Adding content in different text style.

Refer [CoreTextPageViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreTextPageViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010699) link.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `webViewDidFinishLoad` you can do cs-script operation.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{


 NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", webView.frame.size.height, webView.frame.size.width];
    NSString *insertRule2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('p', 'text-align: justify;')"];


      [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];
      [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule2];

}
```